# Import data from Excel to SQL Server by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database

I would be grateful if you can tell me how import data from Excel into a specific column based specific id - my amount of data is huge.

Table in Excel:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | description for id 1 |
| 2 | description for id 2 |
| 3 | description for id 3 |
| 4 | description for id 4 |

My table in SQL Server

| id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | null |
| 2 | two | null |
| 3 | three | null |
| 4 | four | null |

I want a query something like this:

```
if (id in excel == id in SQL Server)
    SQL.description = excel.description
```

Comment: (Edit) Removed the MySQL tag as MySQL <> SQL Server.  I don't think that's possible. How much rows are you talking about? For a moderate amount, probably simpler to import the spreadsheet into a separate work table. UPDATE the main table using a JOIN. Then drop the work table.

Comment: that's good idea , I have 2000 rows

Comment: 2000 rows is nothing in SQL Server. Is there some other reason you're concerned about size? If not, just import the rows into a separate table, do the UPDATE and drop the work table.

Answer (score 0):

In my view , At first you can import all row from excel file into a  table -e.g. excelTable-and finally update mainTable from join table with new table.

1)In SSMS right on your database/Tasks/Import Data
2)Select from excel file
3)update main table
update mainTable set mainTable.description = excelTable.description
from maintable inner join execlTable on mainTable.id = execlTable.id